# psycopg2 - how do I escape single quote when updating a Json column?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to update a json column of a table but got stuck because one of the value in the json has a single quote.

my json string looks like this

```
{"keyword": "women's shoes"}
```

Here is my code.

```
criteria_str = json.dumps(criteria)
sql_str = """update user_saved_search_backup set criteria = '%s'::json where id = %d;""" % (criteria_str, id)                    
write_cursor.execute(sql_str)
```

NOTE: I am using postgreSQL 9.2 which lacks json function support so I had to do this in python

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While `id` is not a Python reserved word, it is a built-in function.  Might be better to avoid its usage as a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a parametrized query. Never directly insert user input into your SQL queries, it exposes you to SQL-injection attacks.

Like this:

```
sql_str = """update user_saved_search_backup set criteria = %s::json where id = %s;"""
write_cursor.execute(sql_str, (criteria_str, id))
```

Here are some helpful [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) on this topic.